# Is there any Android onPreviewFrame similar method in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any Android onPreviewFrame similar method in iOS?

In Android I can easily access raw byte array frames from back/front cameras using next callback method

```
Camera.PreviewCallback.onPreviewFrame(byte[], android.hardware.Camera)
```

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html#onPreviewFrame(byte[], android.hardware.Camera)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html#onPreviewFrame(byte[],%20android.hardware.Camera))

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html

Is there something similar for iOS (Swift), to get `byte[]` frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate/1385775-captureoutput

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, 
                  didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, 
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

we can then try to convert `CMSampleBuffer` in pixel buffer and other formats

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly this is what you need

[AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronousciimagefilteringrequest)

sourceImage: CIImage  -> Getting the Image to be Filtered